# Make C# save a 16-bit bitmap without bitfields compression

Tags: c#, bitmap

When I do a

```
b.Save(outputFilename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

where b is a 16-bit bitmap it is saved with bitfields compression. How can I make C# save without using any compression?

This is what I did with the links that @Ben Voigt posted:

```
ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
Encoder myEncoder ;
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;

myEncoder = Encoder.Compression;
myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/bmp");
myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 
                     (long)EncoderValue.CompressionNone);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

b.Save(outputFilename, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters );
```

When I pass an 8-bit bitmap no compression is used. But when I pass a 16-bit RGB bitmap it still uses bitfields compression.

Comment: BITFIELDS compression is only used in 16 and 32 bit DIBs, and simply describes how the data is packed. In the case of a
16-bit DIB it can define the resolution of the green channel (i.e. 5:6:5 or 5:5:5), where as for 32-bit DIBs it defines
whether the data is stored in RGB or BGR order (and, when using a BMIHv4/5 header, whether the alpha channel is used.)

Can you tell us why do you want to avoid bitfields compression ?

Comment: why isn't it possible to save without compression ?

Comment: Why are you not preferring PNG file format ? for bmp, we have discussed enough about it.

Comment: Well i will have to think about it.

Comment: @MikeNakis Ofcourse, they are just definitions. And to the point, I have already told him that its masks used for packing. I have discussed as much as possible. And those copied paragraphs you say are not something not true but just excerpts from book. I have given him quotes of those links as well. I gave that code just because in case, he is getting the image from somewhere and encoding it again. I saw he is not trying save a 32bpp to 16bpp. But he never answered whether his image is from a server or where. So I answered as much general as you.

Comment: Those paragraphs explain that . there is a line about using masks and the packing in comments. I think I quite explained him. About the code, its nothing to do with saving an image in its own. Since I never got the OP to answer about what the image is , where it comes and stuff like that. I gave that just in case, he receives and encodes it in bitmap. Just a general case. you can see my comments. The first comment here above also said " it simply describes how data is packed ". So how did I misled the OP?!

Comment: "bitfields" isn't compression at all... The compression field is actually a misnomer for "data format".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitmap in windows means DIB.

"A device-independent bitmap (DIB) is a format used to define device-independent bitmaps in various color resolutions. The main purpose of DIBs is to allow bitmaps to be moved from one device to another (hence, the device-independent part of the name). A DIB is an external format, in contrast to a device-dependent bitmap, which appears in the system as a bitmap object (created by an application...). A DIB is normally transported in metafiles (usually using the StretchDIBits() function), BMP files, and the Clipboard (CF_DIB data format)."

And as we have discussed already in comments ,BITFIELDS compression is only used in 16 and 32 bit DIBs, and simply describes how the data is packed. In the case of a 16-bit DIB it can define the resolution of the green channel (i.e. 5:6:5 or 5:5:5), where as for 32-bit DIBs it defines whether the data is stored in RGB or BGR order (and, when using a BMIHv4/5 header, whether the alpha channel is used.)

**There is only one reason to it. It is to keep the BMP to be device independent which is about the format being independent of the device it may be used in. So it means, its always kept in a DIB format according to Windows ! The format is kept intact by means of the compression.**

```
EncoderParameters codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
codecParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L); 
b.Save(outputFilename, myImageCodecInfo, codecparams );
```

This should ensure your quality.

Comment: so you are saying that i cant save it without compression ?

Comment: As of now, MS doesn't prefer to. DIB is what it gives us !

Comment: This makes a good reading though not exactly answering your question but a good one -http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/80551eca-f133-4293-8e8d-3486bbad4cae

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm 

Found an interesting read - Enjoy !! Tells about the evolution of the format over the years !

Comment: is bitfield compression lossless or lossy? If its lossless then its ok with me to use in my application. But if its lossy then it can lead me to problems :(.

Comment: could you please tell me what is RLE encoding ? Is it the same as bitfield compression?

Comment: EncoderParameters codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
codecParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);   
b.Save(outputFilename, myImageCodecInfo, codecparams );

can you try this and tell me. This should solve your problem. And why are you not preferring a PNG format which is lossless provably.

To your above question, they are not same. RLE doesn't apply to 16 bit deep or more images. So I hope, .Net framework also wouldn't have it. Try the above code, its said to give a lossless conversion. And most importantly, where do you get these images from ?

Comment: nope still the 1e hex position has value 03 so therefore still the bitfields compression is being applied. and also the data is not the same as the original because of the compression.

Comment: I have asked you a couple of more questions ?

Where do these images come from ? Do you receive from some server and save them ? Why are you not preferring PNG ?

Comment: you can still use. The data is obviously compressed. Bit fields compression is nothing but masking . 16bpp used a mask of 555 and 32 uses two masks. Bitfield masking is all it means to. It shouldn't be a problem to you. I have given u code to maintain the quality as it is , even if masking happens. I prefer PNG file format though. It is provably lossless. I think I have given you enough reasoning. Lets not beat it around more.

Comment: @klijo As per the implementations of .Net framework, this is what it can guarantee you.

Answer (score 5):

There's an overload of the `Save` function that accepts an `EncoderParameters` argument, via which you can control compression.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression.aspx

Comment: there's not a way to do without compression in his case.

Comment: Bitfield packing is not compression.  And BMP or PNG compression is not lossy anyway, now that klijo has revealed in the comments that he's worried about lossy compression, and not compression in general.

Comment: ofcourse, that's what I tried mentioning it to him. Bitfield packing is not affecting his cause.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your real need is not to "save a 16-bit bitmap without bitfields compression", but to avoid lossy compression.

The problem is that the 16-bit bitmap format by its nature uses bitfields, (something like 5 bits for red, 6 bits for green, and another 5 bits for blue,) so some information will be lost if the original image had a pixel format wider than 16 bits. The most frequently used image format nowadays is the RGB format, which uses 8 bits per pixel, so it requires 3 × 8 = 24 bits per pixel. You simply cannot fit 24 bits of information into 16 bits; some bits will fall off, it is a fact of life.

So, your problem is unsolvable for as long as a 16-bit bitmap is a requirement. The only way around it is to refrain from using 16-bit bitmaps.

Note:

The reason why bitfield compression is used even though you have specified "no compression" is because bitfield compression is not really compression; it is just a pixel format, so it should be called "bitfield format" rather than "bitfield compression". RLE is a real (albeit extremely simple) compression method.

RLE stands for "Run-Length Encoding" and it works as follows: series of identical pixel values of length N are substituted with the number N followed by a single occurence of the pixel value. So, RLE is absolutely lossless.

Comment: what do you mean by "So, RLE is absolutely definitely positively lossless, but that does not help if the underlying pixel format is lossy." ?

Comment: If you use a lossy pixel format such as 16-bit and then compress it with RLE, there will be loss of information, but it will not be due to RLE, it will be due to the use of a lossy pixel format.

Comment: pixel depth has no such connection with lossy. Lossy or lossless is dependent on the compression algorithm. I can't understand why you cant have 16 bit lossless compression.

Comment: RLE cannot be applied to 16 bpp or 32 bpp. Only bitfields compression can be applied to such bitmaps. 8 bpp bitmap is used for RLE. I included the code to keep the quality to be same even when there is compression. And that is said to be lossless. Why are you not preferring PNG ? PNG file format is lossless bitmap. Dont be stuck on DIB.

Comment: @Dumb it appears that you are right about RLE compression not being applicable to 16-bit bitmaps. I will modify my answer. But I originally got this information from you: in a comment under your answer you wrote about bitfield compression "this stuff uses RLE ( run length encoding ) and it is lossless." (and I actually +1ed that comment.)

Comment: @klijo regarding your comment "pixel depth has no such connection with lossy..." It does. Please read my answer again, carefully, from the beginning.

Comment: @MikeNakis i think what you are trying to say is that for large pixel depths its easy to come up with a lossless algorithm and for small pixel depths its not so easy to compress without lossless right ?

Comment: Sorry if I misled you. I wasn't sure of .Net framework implementing RLE for higher bits per pixel. I have commented below that though. Bitfields compressing is nothing but using masks. So shouldn't be a problem for him.

Comment: @klijo I am saying that if you have an 24bpp image and you want to save it in 16bpp format, there will be loss of information in the process of converting each and every 24-bit pixel value to a 16-bit pixel value. It is a law of nature. You cannot fit 3 liters of water in a 2 liter bottle. You cannot fit two feet in one shoe. How can I make it more clear?

Comment: @PeterO thank you for the edit. I suppose you are implying that the term 'lossy' is not applicable to the kind of loss of information incurred by packing pixel values into bitfields. I accept that.

Comment: @MikeNakis - iam not saving a 24 bit image as a 16 bit image. I have image data and i am writing it as a 16 bit color bitmap.

Comment: Your "image data" do not live in la-la-land; they are represented in memory in a certain pixel format. And this pixel format is almost certainly 24-bit. Tell me more about your image data, like what kind of image it is, what it portrays, how you obtained it, etc. and I might be able to help you more.